# setting variables in SQL using conditions

Tags: t-sql, variables

I am creating a report that splits the year into first half second half.  It also look at the same time frame for the previous year to show a comparison.  I am trying to create some variables that work out what the correct date range is depending on how far through the current year we are.

I am encountering a problem with the if statement part and 2 variables are getting set in the second if statement.  I can't see anything wrong.  I know I could pass the variables in the client app and figure it all out there.  I am so close to this working I would like to see it work this way.

```
Declare @CurrDate as date set @CurrDate = convert(datetime,'27/04/2013',103)

Declare @ThisTimeLastYear as date set @ThisTimeLastYear  = dateadd(year,-1,@currdate)

Declare @LastYearCheck as date set @LastYearCheck  = convert(datetime,cast(30 as varchar) + '/' + cast(6 as varchar) + '/' + cast(DATEPART (year,@currdate)-1 as varchar) ,103)
Declare @SpringStartlastYear as date set @springStartlastYear = convert(datetime,'01/01/2012',103)
Declare @AutWinterStartLastYear as date set @AutWinterStartLastYear  = convert(datetime,cast(01 as varchar) + '/' + cast(07 as varchar) + '/' + cast(DATEPART (year,@currdate)-1 as varchar) ,103)

Declare @springEndLastYear as date
Declare @autumnEndLastYear as date 

if (@ThisTimeLastYear < @LastYearCheck)
   set @springEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear 
  /*this year hasn't reached the autumn/winter season so move date ranges out of the way +20 year */
   set @AutWinterStartLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@AutWinterStartLastYear)
   set @autumnEndLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@autumnEndLastYear)
if (@ThisTimeLastYear > @LastYearCheck)
       set @springEndLastYear = @LastYearCheck
set @autumnEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear
```

the 2 variables in the 2nd if statement are altering when they shouldn't.

Comment: your indentation implies that you want multiple lines to be the subject of the `if` - which requires them to be wrapped in `begin` and `end`. if you don't do this - only the line following the `if` is conditional - all subsequent lines are executed regardless of the outcome of the `if`

Comment: Could you provide some possible inputs and expected outputs? I'm not sure I understand what you want returned exactly by this script.

Comment: completely forgot about the begin end!!!! thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything in the output though...

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
if (@ThisTimeLastYear < @LastYearCheck) begin
   set @springEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear 
   /*this year hasn't reached the autumn/winter season so move date ranges out of the way +20 year */
   set @AutWinterStartLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@AutWinterStartLastYear)
   set @autumnEndLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@autumnEndLastYear)
end
if (@ThisTimeLastYear > @LastYearCheck) begin
    set @springEndLastYear = @LastYearCheck
    set @autumnEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear
end
```

or (your condition logic may need some attention):-

```
if (@ThisTimeLastYear < @LastYearCheck) begin
   set @springEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear 
   /*this year hasn't reached the autumn/winter season so move date ranges out of the way +20 year */
   set @AutWinterStartLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@AutWinterStartLastYear)
   set @autumnEndLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@autumnEndLastYear)
end else begin
    set @springEndLastYear = @LastYearCheck
    set @autumnEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use begin/end, here is an alternative: In tsql you can fill out several variables in the same command like this:

```
SELECT 
   @springEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear,
   @AutWinterStartLastYear = DATEADD(year,20,@AutWinterStartLastYear),
   @autumnEndLastYear      = DATEADD(year,20,@autumnEndLastYear)
WHERE @ThisTimeLastYear < @LastYearCheck
SELECT 
   @springEndLastYear = @LastYearCheck,
   @autumnEndLastYear = @ThisTimeLastYear
WHERE @ThisTimeLastYear >= @LastYearCheck
```